# How to custom TabView

Tags: android

I am new to android, i dont know how to do customized TabView. can anyone guide me how to create customized tabview.

Comment: what exactly you want to customize? If don't ask a concrete question, we can't help you.

Comment: We can't awnser this question, please be more specific about the changes you want to make to the TabView. (TabHost(?)) * Edit, Vlad is too fast :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background and the images of tab view with the help of this code

for(int i=0;i

```
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
                {
                   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent); //unselected
                }
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000011")); // selected
        }
```

Comment: did u changed anything other than color in tabbar?

Comment: Also put this code snippet before tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener:- for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
           tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent); //unselected
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000011")); // selected

Comment: No, but we can also put images in the background of tab view

Comment: We don't even know if this is what he wants.